# Xamarin forms : Click event for entry in disable state?

Tags: xamarin.forms

how to add a click event for entry which is in disable state?

I tried with gesture recognizer like below:

```
  <Entry
            TextColor="Black"
            x:Name="phone">
        <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="StartCall"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Entry.GestureRecognizers> 
    </Entry>

 void StartCall(object sender,EventArgs args)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert","Hi","ok");
    }
```

No alert showing on ui when tapping on entry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it gonna work really. The entry component has already a native handler to start the edition of its text when tapped. For this purpose, I suggest you use the `Focused` event instead.

Comment: How about overlapping a transparent view (say a BoxView) over that Entry and create a Tap Gesture for this BoxView?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza My entry is in disable state, I try focused event and it will work only in enable state. I need to fire my entry in disable state.

Comment: So the @Vahid way should work for you. Overlap the entry with another control and put the tap gesture on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your entry inside layout and give GestureRecognizers to layout.
e.g

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry
        Placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
        IsEnabled="False"
        TextColor="Black"
        x:Name="phone"/>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="StartCall"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
        </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Put your Button in a Layout(StackLayout for example) that handles your Event

```
<StackLayout>  
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="StartCall">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers> 
   <!-- InputTransparent="True" to avoid conflicts -->
    <Entry InputTransparent="True"
            TextColor="Black"
            x:Name="phone"/>
<StackLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't it the same answer provided by @HiteshPatil's?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't see it.

Comment: You only need `InputTransparent="True"`, and you shouldn't add `IsEnabled="False"` as this could affect the visual style. It is enabled, but passes input to to the `StackLayout` parent.

Answer (score 3):

As @Diego Rafael Souza said
Entry having Focused event it will fire while user tap on Entry

**XAML:**

```
<Entry Placeholder="Phone number" TextColor="Black" x:Name="phone" Focused="StartCall"/>
```

**.cs:**

```
 void StartCall(object sender, EventArgs args){
        DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hi", "ok");
    }
```

Comment: My entry is in disable state, I try focused event and it will work only in enable state. I need to fire my entry in disable state.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a grid layout

```
<Grid>
    <Entry IsEnabled="False" Text="Hello"/>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EntryTapCommand}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```